# how to use data provided by Facebook using Graph link stat

Tags: php, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

After searching for long time i got this link for getting the details of a `link`

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://www.facebook.com/nokia'
```

Now this is the output i am getting:-

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "url": "http://www.facebook.com/nokia",
         "normalized_url": "http://www.facebook.com/nokia",
         "share_count": 1240,
         "like_count": 8622386,
         "comment_count": 287,
         "total_count": 8623913,
         "commentsbox_count": 2,
         "comments_fbid": 404897301238,
         "click_count": 10
      }
   ]
}
```

After further searching, i was unable to find anything valuable from where i could understand how to use its values.

I explain you how. I have a page where there are 10 different links, now i want to show there total likes, comments and shares. I reached till here but now unable to move further.

How i can use the data provided by facebook on that particular page?

Comment: Are asking how to parse the above data? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you, but that's just JSON. So you just need to use the json_decode method if you're writing in php, then access the 'data' key followed by the 'like_count' key for the likes

Comment: @TommyBs Thanks for the reply, that i know but my issue is i am typing this thing in url, now i dont want to do that, i just want this value to be stored in a variable so that i can use the json_decode function to grab the data.... but how to get this data in a php variable??

Comment: ah ok, if I were you then I would look at using the facebook php-sdk https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/  The section above analytics here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#analytics also describes how to use this in conjunction with the JS-SDK and should be a good starting point

Comment: You can load the results of a FQL query in a PHP array like the sample code in the [FQL Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)